# ReactJS: TypeError: this.ref.current.method is not a function with ant design form

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

```
class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.Child_A = React.createRef();  
        this.Child_B = React.createRef();
    }

    function_uses_Child_A = ()=> {
        // This is working fine
        this.Child_A.current.Child_A_Function()
    }

    function_uses_Child_B = ()=> {
        // This is Does NOT work
        // this.Child_A.current.Child_B_Function() is not a function 
        this.Child_A.current.Child_B_Function()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child_A ref={this.Child_A}/>
                <Child_B ref={this.Child_B}/>   
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent;
```

The above code shows my problem where both has the same code but one works and the other doesn't

This is Child A component:

```
class Child_A extends Component {
    Child_A_Function = () => "Working";
    render = () => <h1>Child_A</h1>
}
export default Child_A;
```

This is Child B component:

```
import {Form} from "antd";

class Child_B extends Component {
    Child_B_Function = () => "Not Working";
    render = () => <h1>Child_B</h1>
}
export default Form.create()(Child_B);
```

I tried to debug `this.Child_B.current`

### [image debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpB09.png)

I believe it shows the Form.create() data and removing mine
I understand this because Child_A works fine and the only different is it doesn't have Form.create()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Form.create()()` is a higher order function which returns another component.

so

```
const DecoratedChild_B = Form.create()(Child_B);
```

DecoratedChild_B may have other wrapper around it, and it become like this:

```
<wrapper ref={this.Child_B}>
   <Child_B/>
</wrapper>
```

That's why you don't get what you want.

to get form ref you should use [wrappedComponentRef](https://github.com/react-component/form#note-use-wrappedcomponentref-instead-of-withref-after-rc-form140)

```
const EnhancedForm = createForm()(Form);
<EnhancedForm wrappedComponentRef={(inst) => this.formRef = inst} />
this.formRef // => The instance of Form
```

if you want something custom, you have to use other name for the ref func

Comment: `render = () =>
        <div>
            <Child_A ref={this.Child_A}/>
            <Child_B wrappedComponentRef={form => this.Child_B = form}/>
        </div>`

Thanks Solved